# Access design time created table and its rows and columns in code in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a table, which I added at design time. its ID is "tblItems"

There is a row in tblItems. whose name is "trItems"

There is a column in trItems named "tdItems"

Now I want to add a button dynamically to tdItems.

How can I add this button?

Comment: There is a code in my mind. Can you read it? Where is your code?

Comment: code for what? Sorry I don't understand what you want

Comment: He is sarcastic and asking you to post your code for us to better help you.

Comment: sorry, I mean which code does he want? I mean I have just created a simple table with two rows and one column using HTML Tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used

```
<td ID = "tdItems" runat = "server">
```

Now I can access this tdItems in my code.

runat = "server" is the key behind that.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList

The following answer is in Java, but it should help: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/526040/Addpluselementsplustoplusaplusdynamicplustwoplusdi

Basically you make an `ArrayList someItem` for `tdItems` and then make another `ArrayList ArrayList` for `trItems`.

What this will look like will vary from the language you are trying to use, but it should work.

To add a row you will add an `ArrayList` to `trItems` and to add a column you will add `someItem` to the required `ArrayList` in `trItems`. This will result in a very awkwardly designed array so to traverse it you will need to get the `.Length;` property from each row before traversing or you could run into errors.

It is better to set the array bounds at compile time and then add items at run time, but some applications simply do not allow this. Without knowing the application of your code, I would advise you to be sure you cannot set the array bounds at compile time first.

Comment: Sorry to say but I think the above suggestion only works when We create table or its rows and columns runtime. or it works when a table or its rows and columns are added at design time but accessible at runtime. My Problem is I have created the table and its rows and columns and I want to access it in code. But I don't know how to access it in code.